# Laravel Bouncer Package sample code does not work

Tags: php, laravel, package

I am using Laravel 5.8, PHP 7.3.3. Installed JosephSilber/bouncer package to manage roles,permissions etc.

I tried this, right from sample, nothing fancy:

```
Bouncer::allow('superuser')->to('create-account'); //works, creates role 'superuser', creates ability 'create-account'
Bouncer::allow('employer')->to('create-employee'); //works
$john = App\User::where('email','john@gmail.com')->first(); //works, finds John
$john->assign('superuser');  //works, John is now a user user
$john->can('create-account'); // works, returns true
$john->can('create-employee'); // works, returns false


$boolean = $john->isAn('superuser') ;
```

> ERROR=> array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Not sure why I get this error. Similar problems with

```
User::whereIs('superuser')->get() etc
```

I tried to debug and the problem seems to when the following line is called inside BaseClipboard.php. It is happening in this call, up to this I can verify the parameters coming in.

```
$authority->roles()->get([
            'name', Models::role()->getQualifiedKeyName()
        ])
```

However I could not get past this. Appreciate any help.

Can't figure out how to get a clean dump of the stack trace. But here is a copy and paste. I assume only the last few will be of interest

> ErrorException
>
> …\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php2029
>
> 51
>
> array_key_exists
>
> …\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php2029
>
> 50
>
> Illuminate\Support\Collection offsetExists
>
> …\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php876
>
> 49
>
> Illuminate\Support\Collection get
>
> …\vendor\silber\bouncer\src\BaseClipboard.php82
>
> 48
>
> Silber\Bouncer\BaseClipboard getRolesLookup
>
> …\vendor\silber\bouncer\src\CachedClipboard.php234
>
> 47
>
> Silber\Bouncer\CachedClipboard Silber\Bouncer{closure}
>
> …\vendor\silber\bouncer\src\CachedClipboard.php248
>
> 46
>
> Silber\Bouncer\CachedClipboard sear
>
> …\vendor\silber\bouncer\src\CachedClipboard.php235
>
> 45
>
> Silber\Bouncer\CachedClipboard getRolesLookup
>
> …\vendor\silber\bouncer\src\BaseClipboard.php57
>
> 44
>
> Silber\Bouncer\BaseClipboard countMatchingRoles
>
> …\vendor\silber\bouncer\src\BaseClipboard.php37
>
> 43
>
> Silber\Bouncer\BaseClipboard checkRole
>
> …\vendor\silber\bouncer\src\Database\Concerns\HasRoles.php92
>
> 42
>
> App\User isAn
>
> …\routes\web.php379
>
> 41
>
> App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider {closure}
>
> …\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php205

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I have edited my OP and added the stack trace. The full stack trace was over 300 lines. Just thought I would narrow it down for you.

Comment: Is this solved??

Comment: No. I stopped calling that function and worked around it.

Answer (score 0):

The permission '**create-employee**' is assigned to '**employer**', not to '**superuser**' role, try this way:

```
Bouncer::allow('superuser')->to('create-account');
Bouncer::allow('superuser')->to('create-employee');
```